# choose profile pic in unity3d for android/ios

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have my profile page displaying user information.
This page has user's image and i want to allow user to choose his pic.

So is there any way to open dialog box to choose pic from android/iOS device in unity3d ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the various Prime31 plugins for accessing the CameraRoll and photographs storage. There are many other assets available on the Asset Store that also provide the same functionality. It is not possible to do this directly through Unity without some programming effort.

Comment: thanks Justin for your help...let me check Prime[31] then ... UniFileBrowser is one option i found till now